# I can't add new controller and view. It gives error "Command "SaveAll" is not valid"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

When i try to add new controller or new view in asp.net mvc project, the following error occurs
" There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Command "SaveAll" is not valid.' "

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE4v1.png)[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfIUh.png)
It happens only when i try to add controller or view only in one project, other projects are working normal . . . .

Comment: Please describe with details .

Comment: Have you using EF in your project? Try dereferencing EF then add again. If it still persists, seems that related to scaffolding error (use Add => New Item => MVC Controller instead).

Comment: I am trying to add in this way, Right click on Controllers => Add => Controllers => (this screen appers) http://prntscr.com/d8rbyo => then i select top one 'MVC 5 Controller- Empty' => then error occurs mentioned above